# laravel : how to filter records from database side

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

how to filter records in database side ? i mean when i use something like

```
model::whereIn('id' , [1,2,3] )->get(['id' , 'name'])
```

it retrieve records with all columns then filter them in PHP side. is there anyway to filter rocords in db side ?

Comment: That's not true. The columns already get filtered in the database. Why do you assume they don't?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this

```
model::whereIn('id' , [1,2,3] )->select('id', 'name')->get()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code **already does that** `get(['id', 'name'])` overrides the SQL `select` columns internally before executing the query. It does not fetch all columns and then filter out the unnecessary ones.

It's the exact same as `->select('id', 'name')->get()` which was suggested in the other answers, it's only a shorter version to use (Laravel has a lot of these alternative methods to allow developers to use whatever seems right/readable for them).

If you want, you can dump the last query executed by doing this:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();

YourModel::whereIn('id' , [1,2,3])->get(['id' , 'name']);

dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

You'll see that it outputs the following query:

```
select `id`, `name` from `your_model` where `id` in (?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Model::whereIn('id' , [1,2,3] )->select('id', 'name')->get();
```

To verify you are filtering on database side replace `get` with `toSql()`.

```
$result = Model::whereIn('id' , [1,2,3] )->select('id', 'name')->toSql(); 
dd ( $result );
```

You'll get the following result

> "select `id`, `name` from `model` where `id` in (?, ?, ?)"